# How to use Frida on a Java application ? (non Android application)

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am trying to use Frida on a Java application which is obfuscated with ZKM (Zelix KlassMaster).

When I attach to the process, it seems the JVM is not loaded:

```
[Local::PID::23585]-> Java.available

false
```

I have the same behavior on Burp which is run by the following command :

- java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -jar -Xmx2g burpsuite_free.jar

Does anyone know why Frida does not detect the JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge, Frida has no support for non-android java applications.

For desktop java applications you are better of using [Java agents](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/) or the lower level JVM-TI interface. There's also the [pyspresso](https://github.com/CrowdStrike/pyspresso) framework which uses the [Java Debug Wire Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) to debug java applications using a python code base.

Also have a look at [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/dynamic-java-instrumentation?rq=1) answer for more ideas.

Comment: Since Frida 12.10 there is also support for HotSpot JVM (non-Android) https://frida.re/news/2020/06/29/frida-12-10-released/